# How to print certain rows per screen/page in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm a CS student, fairly new to **assembly language programming**. In this assignment, I generated many numbers after certain calculations.

Then I was asked to show 30 rows of results per page and the user should be able to “Press any key to continue …” to view the next page. I was wondering where should I look into to make this work?

I used column and columnMax to display 10 results per line, as also requested by this assignment. But I have no idea how I could limit the max rows shown on a page (for a page break) for the output of MASM.

It would be great if anyone would kindly point me in the correct direction, please.

Comment: Are you trying to set the screen resolution / font size so that 30 lines will exactly fill a screen?  If not, it doesn't take any special functions, just count lines you're printing and do something different every N lines, just like you would in any language.  e.g. inner loop to print 30 lines / outer loop to prompt.  Exactly like you'd do it in C, for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, you mean I can just use a counter to count 30 lines, and then prompt "Press any key to continue...", and then go on? Oh, I thought this is something special that I need to set with a special directive or function. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!!